# Not able to add Windows Server in Azure Backup Server Protection Group

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

In azure, i created 3 Windows server VM i.e. one for Azure Backup Server (let say BackupServer), one for Active Directory on VM (let say ADServer), and last SQL Server on Windows Server(let say SQLServer) . All three are on same Domain. Now while adding SQLServer to Protection Group in Azure Backup Server Configuration, then it is giving me error as attached in the screenshot.

Tried many links available on the internet but no luck.
Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: For test, could you please disable the windows firewall of SQL server?

Comment: Hi @JasonYe-MSFT. Disabling the Firewall for both Domain and Private works . But is it ok to disable firewalls for security concern?

Comment: We can follow official article to config windows firewall settings, please check my answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it ok to disable firewalls for security concern?

You are right, disable firewall just for test, we should follow this [official article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757794(v=sc.12).aspx) to config firewall settings for DPM.
[image]

By the way, Azure VM have NSG to block outside network traffic.

Comment: I already did for 135. Not sure for others. Have to check. Anyway thanks.